# Disabling Nouveau to install NVIDIA on CentOS 7.6 causes blank monitor

Tags: centos, grub2, nvidia, nouveau

I'm trying to install NVIDIA drivers on an embedded system running CentOS 7.6 that has a Quadro P5000 GPU. I'm generally following the instructions outlined [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-centos-7-linux) but my monitor does not display anything other than a blinking cursor rebooting after Step 4. Removing the lines that disable Nouveau in my GRUB allow me to boot and log in, so I suspect that is the culprit. Why does that happen when Nouveau is disabled, and how can I install the NVIDIA drivers if I can't seem to disable the Nouveau ones?

EDIT: Finishing the NVIDIA install using ssh on another machine does not solve this problem. I see more steps of the boot process on the monitor when i remove rhgb quiet in my boot parameters, but at some point, no more steps render and I'm left with a blinking cursor

EDIT 2: TL;DR summary: I can't see anything on my monitor on boot after a certain point no matter what I do after I disable Nouveau. I need to disable it in order to install NVIDIA, so I am stuck here.

Comment: So, does it hang for real?  Or is it just booting to a blinking cursor because there is no graphical driver?  Those instructions don’t say to rebuild the initrd, nor does it disable nouveau from being loaded, so it’s probably failing to load the nvidia driver.   Does switching to a different VT work(control-alt-F2)?  Does removing the “rhgb quiet” when adding the modest argument provide more details?  In general I usually tell people to not install the nvidia.sh drivers, instead use the elrepo drivers instead, because they handle it for you.

Comment: @jsbillings It does hang. Leaving it on overnight did not solve anything, and switching to a different VT doesn't work. Removing "rhgb quiet" was also no help. I've made a bit of progress since I initially posted, however. I was able to install the NVIDIA drivers by unplugging my monitor into the system and ssh'ing into it from another machine. HOWEVER, I cannot boot into the machine as long as a monitor is plugged in, even with the NVIDIA drivers installed and running.

Comment: @jsbillings Actually, you were right, the system does boot. I just don't see the boot finish when the monitor is plugged in. 'lshw -numeric -C display` lists an ASPEED display device along with my NVIDIA running a driver named asd but the VGA display out of the system only works if the driver running on the NVIDIA is Nouveau and not NVIDIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with the embedded system I am using. The problem is one of the display drivers doesn't work on CentOS 7.3 and up. Blacklisting that driver AND Nouveau allowed me to continue installation without issue.

https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=27624